# How to concatenate arrays element recursively

Tags: php

I'm working on a project and I'm stacked since 2 days, this is my problem: I have two `arrays` and want to retrieve the second item in each object in *Array_2* and `concatenate` it to the content of each object in first *Array_1* in `PHP`.

Array_1

```
 [[1453274700000,24011],[1453275000000,24222],[1453275300000,24284],[1453275600000,24331],...]
```

Array_2

```
[[1453274700000,51951],[1453275000000,52093],[1453275300000,52251],[1453275600000,52288],...]
```

Wanted_array

```
[[1453274700000,24011,51951],[1453275000000,24222,52093],[1453275300000,24284,52251],[1453275600000,24331,52288]...]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Why isn't it working? This should be fairly simple: Make a loop that runs through array1 and array2 and save item 0 (eg. `1453274700000`) as the key and item 1 (eg. `24011`) as the value. After this, simply run through both of them and match up the keys. If the sorting of the arrays is always identical you can do this with a single `for` loop.

Comment: You mean to merge these arrays into equal indexes of each array ?

Answer (score 1):

A functional solution:

```
$result = array_map(function (array $a1, array $a2) {
    return array_merge($a1, [$a2[1]]);
}, $array_1, $array_2);
```

This assumes that all items are in order and only need to be merged by their order, not by their first value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and add second item from `$array2` if it exists.

```
$array1 = array(
    array(1453274700000,24011),
    array(1453275000000,24222),
    array(1453275300000,24284),
    array(1453275600000,24331)
    );

$array2 = array(
    array(1453274700000,51951),
    array(1453275000000,52093),
    array(1453275300000,52251),
    array(1453275600000,52288),
    );


array_walk($array1, function(&$item, $key) use ($array2){
    if(isset($array2[$key][1])){
        $item[] = $array2[$key][1];
    }
});

print_r($array1);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453274700000
            [1] => 24011
            [2] => 51951
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275000000
            [1] => 24222
            [2] => 52093
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275300000
            [1] => 24284
            [2] => 52251
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275600000
            [1] => 24331
            [2] => 52288
        )

)
```

**EDIT**

As @h2ooooooo pointed out that there could be possibility that array items are in random order. If array items can be in random order and they are matched with first index value, use this (works with PHP >= 5.5.0):

```
$array1 = array(
    array(1453274700000,24011),
    array(1453275000000,24222),
    array(1453275300000,24284),
    array(1453275600000,24331),
    array(1453276000000,24222) // no match in $array2
    );

$array2 = array(
    array(1453275000000,52093),
    array(1453274700000,51951),
    array(1453275300000,52251),
    array(1453275600000,52288),
    );


array_walk($array1, function(&$item, $key) use ($array2){
    // Find match in $array2
    $array2_key = array_search($item[0], array_column($array2, 0));
    // If match found
    if($array2_key !== false && isset($array2[$array2_key][1])){
        $item[] = $array2[$array2_key][1];
    }
    // No match
    else{
        $item[] = null;
    }
});

print_r($array1);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453274700000
            [1] => 24011
            [2] => 51951
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275000000
            [1] => 24222
            [2] => 52093
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275300000
            [1] => 24284
            [2] => 52251
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275600000
            [1] => 24331
            [2] => 52288
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453276000000
            [1] => 24222
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `$item[0]` to define what "group" each value belongs to, you can iterate through the first array and save `$item[0]` as the key and `$item[1]` as the value. Do the same for the second array. Now iterate through the saved array for array1, and check if the saved array for array2 contains the same keys. Do the same for array2 (in case it has key that array1 doesn't have), and save it all to a new array:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(
        array('1453274700000',24011),
        array('1453275000000',24222),
        array('1453276000000',24222), // inexistent in $arr2
    );

$arr2 = array(
        array('1453275000000',52093),
        array('1453274700000',51951),
        array('1453273000000',24222), // inexistent in $arr1
    );

$arr1dictionary = [];
$arr2dictionary = [];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $collection) {
  $arr1dictionary[$collection[0]] = $collection[1];
}

foreach ($arr2 as $collection) {
  $arr2dictionary[$collection[0]] = $collection[1];
}

foreach ($arr1dictionary as $key => $value) {
  if (isset($arr2dictionary[$key])) {
    $result[$key] = [$key, $value, $arr2dictionary[$key]];
  } else {
    $result[$key] = [$key, $value, null];
  }
}

foreach ($arr2dictionary as $key => $value) {
  if (isset($result[$key])) {
    continue;
  }

  $result[$key] = [$key, null, $value];
}

$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453274700000
            [1] => 24011
            [2] => 51951
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453275000000
            [1] => 24222
            [2] => 52093
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453276000000
            [1] => 24222
            [2] => (null, the value only exists in $arr1)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1453273000000
            [1] => (null, the value only exists in $arr2)
            [2] => 24222
        )

)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/505024)